# R library in Android error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have been using this [Android Guide](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Android-Application-Development-For-Dummies.productCd-047077018X,navId-322496,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html)

While it has been a pleasant experience so far, I am experiencing my first problem. I copied all the code from the source that is in the link, and pasted it to the project folder, replacing all old files. 
Before starting to understand what I had pasted, I thought it would be logical to run the code first to check for problems. The project wouldn't run because of an R object missing. After importing it (Eclipse's solution to the problem), more errors popped up. I tried searching for an answer, both on the Internet and in the book, but to no avail.
 Since my software is up to date, I doubt this is a problem on the software's side. And since the code is available online, I think the problem would have popped up and been fixed.

Thank you in advance for the help. For extra details please ask in the comments.

```
The code:

    MainActivity.java

        package com.dummies.android.silentmodetoggle;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
        import android.media.AudioManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private AudioManager mAudioManager; 
        private boolean mPhoneIsSilent;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

            checkIfPhoneIsSilent(); 

            setButtonClickListener();

            Log.d("SilentModeApp", "This is a test");
        }    

        private void setButtonClickListener() {
         Button toggleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton); 
         toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
                    // Change back to normal mode
                    mAudioManager
                            .setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = false;
                } else {
                    // Change to silent mode
                    mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    mPhoneIsSilent = true;
                }

                // Now toggle the UI again
                toggleUi();
            }
        }); 
       }

    /**
     * Checks to see if the phone is currently in silent mode. 
     */
    private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent() {
        int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();
        if (ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
            mPhoneIsSilent = true;
        } else {
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Toggles the UI images from silent
     * to normal and vice versa.
     */
    private void toggleUi() {

        ImageView imageView = 
            (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);
        Drawable newPhoneImage;

        if (mPhoneIsSilent) {
            newPhoneImage = 
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_silent);

        } else {
            newPhoneImage = 
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.phone_on);
        }

        imageView.setImageDrawable(newPhoneImage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
        toggleUi();
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried to import the project rather than paste it. The clean tip worked then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **cleaning** your project, this will rebuild your R file. If there is still no R file in your file-tree then you may have an error in one your xml layout files. Eclipse may not tell you this so be vigilant and check through all the files in the /res folder. 
Also, **never** import R when this happens.

Comment: How do I clean it? I'm new to java and app development, ans also to Eclipse.

Comment: Go to "clean..." in the Project tab at the top

Comment: Didn't work. The main_activity.xml is bug free, while the main.xml in the menu folder has a problem in android:title="@string/action_settings".

Comment: It is described as unfindable. Do you think the two errors are related?

Comment: Make sure you delete the import R as well

Comment: Did so. Still nothing.

Comment: Make sure you check all your xml files for any mistakes, including strings and styles. Also check the manifest.

Comment: Tried to, nothing worked. Can you please check the code yourself?

Comment: Edit your question to include the logcat errors as well as code

Comment: The logs are empty, the project won't compile. I will enter the codes.

Comment: I have completed the pasting

Comment: Your problem is that R is not being generated, this is probably due to a mistake in an xml file. Try rebuilding the project and cleaning again and check all the xml changes you made. Then check if the R file is generated in the "generated files".

Comment: Where can I build it, the build tools are greyed out.

Comment: uncheck build automatically and keep trying to clean it.

Comment: Still nothing. Can it actually be a bug of sorts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61440/discussion-between-user2977079-and-bennef).

Comment: That's not what chat is for, there are lots of pages on this problem if you search. I'll bet it's something you did in an xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there is a variable named **action_settings** in **/res/values/string.xml** if it does not exist please **create one** and then clean using projects -> clean makesure that build Automatically is checked